# Are normally distributed residuals not necessarily homoskedastic?

Tags: regression, variance, modeling, residuals, diagnostic

Let's say I've ran a linear regression and I'm checking the model diagnostics. I made a histogram of the residuals and they appear more or less normally distributed as below.

I thought for a long time that normally distributed residuals like below also indicated that the residuals are homeskedastic. However, I am I right in saying that heteroeskedastic residuals like below would also be normally distributed? Or in other words, we cannot tell if residuals are homeskedastic or heteroeskedastic just by plotting a histogram?

[image]

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that a marginal distributions of residuals looking normal would indicate homoskedasticity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely right, normally distributed does not imply homoskedastic, and your example is great.